# How to max out halfling Adaptable Luck?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, halfling

I have a halfling who took the alternate racial feature **Adaptable Luck** (Advanced Race Guide), giving me a luck bonus to things +1 after a roll or +2 before.

I took the trait **Fate's Favored** (Ultimate Campaign), increasing by the bonus by one.

I took the feat **Fortunate One** (Advanced Race Guide), as a pre-req to **Adaptive Fortune** (Advanced Race Guide), which increases it by +2.

So this would give me +4 after or +5 before the roll.

Are there any other feats, magic items, or spells to push the adaptable luck bonus even higher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [truly fortunate feat (3pp)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/rite-publishing/general-feats-3rd-party-rite-publishing/truly-fortunate/) has a 44% chance of giving you a 5 or 6 luck bonus after the roll, and it has a separate 1 use per day. This isn't exactly what you were looking for but it is close.

Other than that, probably not. There are no pages on d20pfsrd.com that specifically mention "adaptable luck" AND do what you want. You can google [site:www.d20pfsrd.com/ "adaptable luck"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS709US709&espv=2&q=site%3Awww.d20pfsrd.com%2F%20%22adaptable%20luck%22&oq=site%3Awww.d20pfsrd.com%2F%20%22adaptable%20luck%22&gs_l=serp.3...19091.29768.0.30257.16.16.0.0.0.0.61.786.15.15.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.0.0.a3OJyprmoKs), if you want to check my work.

The halfling favored class bonus for the [Occultist (3pp)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/radiance-house/occultist/), gives you additional uses. This makes the bonus more useful, but doesn't satisfy the requirements of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Bob, I checked d20pfsrd for anything that might increase an existing luck bonus (similar to what [Moment of Greatness](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/moment-of-greatness/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjQh-iEsJjTAhUJVrwKHaNyDI0QFggEMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNGOgkB4Rg67MfIuuNY8cRoXUsWz7Q) does for a Morale bonus), but could not find anything other than what you already have.